# Repeated retrieval in result set returns null

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm having an issue with `ResultSet.getString` where when I call it the first time it returns the value but the second time returns null (this without closing the resultset or the sql connection)

```
if (rs.getString(i) == null) {
    properties.setProperty(metaData.getColumnLabel(i), "");
} else {
    properties.setProperty(metaData.getColumnLabel(i), rs.getString(i));
}
```

of course the code is easily fixable to avoid the second call to `rs.getString()` but what I want to understand is why the second return null if the first one didn't

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html):

> For maximum portability, result set columns within each row should be read in left-to-right order, and each column should be read only once.

Under the hood, you are consuming bytes from a TCP stream, so it isn't too surprising that you can't retrieve the same column value twice.

Comment: In a lot of drivers doing repeated or out of order retrievals of column values would work.

Comment: I'm using microsoft sql server jdbc drive 1.2.2

Comment: @MarkRotteveel No doubt, but they aren't obliged to behave that way by the JDBC Specification.